# Return Wrong Value of NameIdentifier in User.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

i'm using Asp.net core 3.1 and User.Identity to get UserId , Recently some of our users have reported a problem that they're seeing another user Account Instead of seeing their own account when logged in .
here is the code that i think is the cause of this problem :

```
User.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

the Extensions i have used:

```
        public static string FindFirstValue(this IIdentity identity, string claimType)
        {
            var claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            return claimsIdentity?.FindFirstValue(claimType);
        }
```

```
        public static string FindFirstValue(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string claimType)
        {
            return identity?.FindFirst(claimType)?.Value;
        }
```

Other information :

1. Cache is not activate
2. Users have reported this Problem less than 5%
3. **User.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)** Used in a ViewComponent

Comment: maybe u can use something like that. ```public string getCurrentUser()
        {
            var userID = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            return userID;
        }```

Comment: thanks for your comment .
i don't think that makes any different and beside, i'm using it already .
the problem is that *User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)* return a wrong value . @BerkGarip

Comment: my idea is , if its working in a wrong way u better made ur codes much easy to fix it. i would definitely do that. if its still working in a wrong way, i would consider to give less claims when the user authtenticate.